# Как определить ближайший объект к пользователю и вывести содержание его балуна?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

На сайте Яндекс карт есть решение определяющее ближайшее кафе к месту клика на карте https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/find_closest_object

Нам необходимо при загрузке сайта определять место пользователя и при успешном определении показывать пользователю ближайший к нему объект(магазин). Причем показывать не на карте, а выводить адрес и название магазина в div.

Пока приходит в голову только поместить содержимое балуна в переменную и выводить эти данные в div.

Вопросы:
Как вот здесь

```
myMap.events.add('click', function (event) {
magaz.getClosestTo([59.935906, 30.323186]).balloon.open();
```

получить balloonContent?

Можно ли определять местоположение пользователя с сайта без https?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вернуть содержимое балуна можно так:

```
cafe.getClosestTo(event.get('coords')).properties.get('balloonContent')
```

"Можно ли определять местоположение пользователя с сайта без https?" Можно, но оно будет менее точным. Такое ограничение у браузера.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А как теперь вместо event.get('coords') подгрузить местоположение пользователя вот отсюда https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation?

Comment: а что у вас не получается?

Comment: не понимаю какую переменную туда ставить. В примере идет определение сначала по ip, а потом из браузера. И как результат этих проверок положить в переменную я не очень представляю=(( недостаточно знаний по js

Comment: Не нужно два раза определять геолокацию, достаточно её определить один раз так geolocation.get().then(function (result) {var coords = result.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(); cafe.getClosestTo(coords).properties.get('balloonContent')
});